# PhoneGap Build - Iframe Blocked

Tags: phonegap-build, phonegap

I'm building an app in PhoneGap but it is blocking the Iframe, any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: please share what you have coded so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include in your xml config file :

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" />
```

And access all origins.